# How to implement office button like functionality in Qt 4.7?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm implementing a ribbon based GUI using Qt 4.7 and VC++ on Visual Studio 2010. I made ribbons successfully but I have no idea how to add a office button functionality on the window frame border.

Office button : [office button](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/what-and-where-is-the-microsoft-office-button-HA010182895.aspx)

Comment: I doubt Qt has a similar feature.  But you can always use the Win32 api: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It's OS specific and not trivial. See for example: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/26640

Comment: Qt 4.7 is significantly outdated. Consider switching to latest Qt version. (It still doesn't have this feature, though.)